# getting message file not supported After downloading image file in nodejs . I'm uploading file from angular7 using Formdata

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, angular, multipartform-data

I'm sending the image using formdata in angular to my nodejs api. and in nodejs i'm storing that file at myfolder but when i open my stored image file its shows 
`"Abc.jpeg It appears that we don't support this file format"`

From nodejs i used multiparty, then i used formidable but getting same error in both
I compared the size of file before uploading (original file) size was 78kb but after uploading the file size become 111kb.

**Nodejs Code**

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
    console.log(files.fileDetails.path);
    var oldpath = files.fileDetails.path;
    var newpath = 'C:/storage/myfolder/' + files.fileDetails.name;
    fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
    });
})
```

**Angular Code**

```
public OnSubmit(formValue: any) {
    let main_form: FormData = new FormData();
    for(let j=0;j<this.totalfiles.length; j++) {
        console.log("the values is ",<File>this.totalfiles[j]);
        console.log("the name is ",this.totalFileName[j]);
        main_form.append(fileDetails,this.totalfiles[j])
    }
    console.log(formValue.items)

    this._SocietyService.postFiles(main_form).subscribe(data => {
        console.log("result is ", data)
    })
}
```

Comment: could you check your `Content-Type:` parameter inside the network tab of chrome while making the post request from browser it should be something like this  `Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=SOME_BOUNDARY`

Comment: yes it is multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryLpXdZWRdZVGVBGYA

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = require('path')
var multer = require('multer')

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: 'C:/storage/myfolder/',
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })
```

You can use the [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) its a vary handy middleware to handle `form/multipart` data.